# Laravel 5 Eloquent ManyToMany relationship query

Tags: php, laravel, laravel-5, eloquent, laravel-5.3

In my mySQL database I have 3 tables:

- cocktails
- ingredients
- cocktail_ingredient

I can choose multiple ingredients ID, ex. [1,50,60,7,3]
I need to find the cocktails that I can prepare with ONLY this list of ingredients. It is possible to have less ingredients but they ALL must be presents in my ingredients list [1,50,60,7,3].

I declared my ManyToMany relationship, i created my Models, everything works, now I try to create my query with the ORM:

```
    $ids = [1,50,60,7,3];
    $coktails = Cocktail::has('ingredients','<=',count($ids))
                        ->whereHas('ingredients',function($q) use ($ids){
                            $q->whereIn('ingredients.id',$ids);
                        })
                        ->get();
```

I tried also:

```
    $coktails = Cocktail::has('ingredients','<=',count($ids))
                        ->whereHas('ingredients',function($q) use ($ids){
                            foreach ($ids as $id){
                                $q->where('ingredients.id',$id);
                            }
                        })
                        ->get();
```

It's always a wrong count, i know my problem is in my whereHas Closure, but i can't find it.

Thank you

Answer (score 2, accepted):

In your example, your target list of ingredients is `[1,50,60,7,3]`. Imagine you have a cocktail that requires ingredients `[1, 2]`.

Based on your current logic:

- `has('ingredients', '<=', count($ids))` will match, because `2 <= 5`, and
- `whereHas('ingredients', function($q) use ($ids) { $q->whereIn('ingredients.id', $ids); })` will match, because the subquery will return a record for id 1, and, by default, `whereHas` is only looking for at least one record.

So, based on that logic, cocktail with ingredients `[1, 2]` will be returned, and that is not what you want.

What you're really looking for is to make sure that you only get cocktails that don't have any ingredients that are not in your target list of ids. `[1, 50]` should match, since it is a subset, but `[1, 2]` should not, because ingredient `2` is not in the original set.

To handle this, you'll want to use a combination of the `whereDoesntHave` method and the `whereNotIn` method.

```
$ids = [1,50,60,7,3];
$cocktails = Cocktail::whereDoesntHave('ingredients', function($q) use ($ids) {
                        $q->whereNotIn('ingredients.id', $ids);
                    })
                    ->get();
```

This statement is saying "get all the cocktails that don't have an ingredient that is not in this list of ingredients." `[1, 50]` will match, because it doesn't have any ingredients that are not in the list. However, `[1, 2]` will not match, because it does have an ingredient that is not in the list (`2`).